# iPhone memory pages

Tags: iphone, memory-management

My app crashes because of low memory.
This is the extraction from low memory crash log:

Free pages:        802
Active pages:      3448
Inactive pages:    2120
Throttled pages:   97661
Purgeable pages:   0
Wired pages:       24643
Largest process:   MobileSafari

Do you know how many kilo bytes 1 page represent?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A page is 4kB on iOS. This is documented in the [Memory Usage Performance Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/performance/conceptual/managingmemory/articles/aboutmemory.html).